# Vertically Centering a section title

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

How can I center a the section title "Summary Sheet" Vertically?[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\subsectionfont{\centering}
\fancyhf{} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Header}}
\cfoot{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Footer}}

\begin{document}
\title{\vspace{-40mm}\Huge Compressed Air} 
\date{\Large ATLAS COPCO}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newpage

\section{Summary Sheet}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \vspace*{\fill}\section{Summary Sheet}\vspace*{\fill} ?

Comment: @Ignasi Tried that but it moved way too down towards the bottom, not centered actually

Comment: Do you mean halfway down the page (i.e., vertically) or midway between the margins (i.e., horizontally)?